# Topology of simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm trying to prove that the topology of $|K|$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the same as the topology of $|K|$ obtained as a quotient space.
I was thinking on the equivalence relation of that identification in this way:
$ \sigma$ ~ $\tau \iff \sigma \cap \tau \neq \varnothing$, or in the case of abstract simplicial complexes in this way:$\sigma$ ~ $\tau \iff \sigma \subseteq \tau$ or $\tau \subseteq \sigma$.
However, those aren't equivalent relations since the transitivity doesn't hold. Can someone please tell me which is the equivalence relation?

Comment: Can you specify the definitions a bit more? $\sigma\sim\tau\Leftrightarrow \sigma\cap\tau\neq\emptyset$ doesn't seem to be very meaningful... One way of obtaining the realization $|K|$ is to take a disjoint union of *all* geometric simplices in $K$ (of all dimensions) and identify faces of each simplex with the simplices that actually *are* its faces.

Comment: I think I understand the identification but I don't know how to express it well. If I write $\sigma$ ~ $\tau \iff \sigma$ is a face of $\tau$, that relation must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. But in that way it is not symmetric, since $\tau$ is not related with $\sigma$.

Comment: You just say which simplex you identify with which other simplex. Actually, there are at least 2 quite readable (slightly different) definitions on wikipedia, did you read that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex#Geometric_realization